# Orbeon: How to do checkbox list with optional text input

Tags: checkbox, orbeon, xforms

I need to do checkbox list from dictionary, but I have to add optional text input to every option, something like this:

```
<li>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="{id}"> {name}
  </label>
  <input type="text">
</li>
```

Dictionary looks like that:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <id/>
    <name/>
  </item>
</items>
```

I tried to make it with `select` but I can't put text input next to every item. I think I could do it with `repeat` but I dont know how to connect checkboxes(which are true/false only) with text inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're asking the question is the context of XForms, and more specifically Orbeon Forms, since you've tagged your question as such. So, with XForms, this is done with a selection control:

```
<xf:select appearance="full" ref=".">
    <xf:itemset ref="instance('items')/item">
        <xf:label ref="name"/>
        <xf:value ref="id"/>
    </xf:itemset>
</xf:select>
```

Also see the [full source](https://gist.github.com/avernet/c2d54f0d13ad603b005a) of an example doing this, which you can also [run directly](http://demo.orbeon.com/orbeon/xforms-sandbox/run?url=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/avernet/c2d54f0d13ad603b005a/raw/gistfile1.xml).